# printing a matrix from script in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have written a script (.m file) in matlab which uses one function to store the final result in a variable `Y`. 
Here is the script

```
A = importdata('LineMat.txt',' ',1) ; 
lineData = A.data ; 
Y = Y_Bus_Formation(lineData) ; 
disp(Y) ;
```

Here `Y_Bus_Formation()` is a function defined by me which returns a matrix . I wrote the `disp(Y)` to display the output but it doesn't work ie when I run the script , it shows in the variables of the workspace a new variable `Y` but nothing is printed on the screen .

How should I do it ?

Comment: That should have worked. Also you can just type `Y` with no `;` at end to print to the screen.

Comment: I think it means Y is empty.

Comment: @Dan I tried that it is not working

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg , Y is not coming empty

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw If you type `Y` or `disp(Y)` in the command line after you run the script, does it display then?

Comment: put your `Y_Bus_Formation` code on here so we can see it. It seems as if it is returning an empty matrix.

Comment: output of `whos` might help, too

Comment: Try to display the matrix in the last line of the script and check the matrix.

Comment: If it's not empty, then size(Y) will return some non-zero values - one way to check if it is fine.  If it isn't empty, then typing Y as the others have said will work.